# How to interpret or translate “para installiert” in a song by Deichkind?

Tags: meaning, etymology, lyrics

What does *para installiert* or *parainstalliert* mean in the German song *Like Mich Am Arsch* by Deichkind?

The phrase is used in the following text context:

> Shitstorm-Angriff, Para installiert. Gefällt mir!

or should it be written as

> Shitstorm-Angriff parainstalliert. Gefällt mir!

The Duden describes para~ as prefix for "alongside".
Should this be interpreted as "Shitstorm attack installed alongside. Like!"

Comment: Nothing, it's just namesdropping and techno-babbling gibberish.

Comment: The guy is obviously browsing Facebook and reading a lot of junk on the web. "Para installiert" is probably something he found on AliExpress, a platform for small shops in China (owned by Alibaba), with often terrible translations. I found the line "Heißer verkauf 1 para installiert faser lange wimpern natürlich dicke falschen wimpern mode" in one of the offers. IOW: it is very likely badly translated Chinese. Alternatively, he installed Para (Para-Welt.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received a response from the Deichkind team:

> 'Para installiert' bedeutet, dass die Paranoia in Deinem Gehirn
>   installiert wurde durch eine virale Attacke.

Answer (score 5):

Der Songtext ist ein Mischmasch aus Versatzstücken aktueller Onlinekommunikation, verfremdet und neu zusammengesetzt, so wird aus

- Like mich
- Leck mich am Arsch (zeitlose Beleidigung, die schon Goethe so ähnlich verwendete)
- Like mich am Arsch

oder aus

- gefällt mir,
- weil ich ein Mädchen bin
- Gefällt mir, dass es ein Mädchen wird

Zu para installiert würde ich, mit einem begrenzten Einblick in Facebook- und WhatsApp-Kommunikation Jugendlicher und junger Erwachsener vermuten, dass es eine Verballhornung des Begriffs *paralysiert* ist, sich womöglich (auch) auf parallel installiert bezieht, aber als gängige Abkürzung dafür ist es mir noch nicht über den Weg gelaufen.

Das offizielle Video http://www.startup-humor.de/deichkind-like-mich-am-arsch/ zeigt keine sehr enge Verknüpfung von Text und Bild. Zum fraglichen Text sieht man jemanden kiffen aber nichts, was mit der Installation von irgendwas zu tun hat und auch für die Vorsilbe `para` gibt es wenig her.

Allerdings vermeldet *mtwde* hilfreich in einem Kommentar, dass "Paras schieben" für "paranoide Symptome zeigen" verwendet wird. Da kann dann doch ein vager Bezug zur Intoxikation mit psychoaktiven Substanzen hergestellt werden und es lässt sich gut eine Brücke schlagen, zum zuvor erwähnten Shitstorm, während `installiert` wieder den Bezug zur Smartphonewelt mit ihren Apps herstellt.

Comment: Ich halte eine Anspielung auf den Begriff "Paras schieben" für wahrscheinlicher. Entsprechend dann "Paranoia/Verfolgungswahn installiert". Sehr viel sinnvoller macht es den Ausdruck aber trotzdem nicht.

Comment: Aha. Nun "Paras schieben" ist mir ungeläufig - wenn das ein verbreiteter Begriff in einer gewissen Szene ist, dann ist das eine naheliegende Interpretation.

Comment: Ein sehr sorgfältig formulierte Antwort auf eine recht schludrig formulierte Frage... Interessant, wie viele sinnvolle Interpretationen "para" zulässt. Ich hätte vielleicht noch eine: *para* als falsche Übersetzung für *prä* von *präinstalliert*, vielleicht? (Abgesehen davon kann man sich über den Nutzen des Worts *präinstalliert* natürlich streiten.)

Answer (score 0):

"Gefällt mir, dass es ein Mädchen wird - 
Shitstorm Angriff, para-installiert"

Parallel zu seiner Aussage, dass es ihm gefalle, dass es ein Mädchen wird, installiert er einen Shitstorm-Angriff.

Ich verstehe nicht wie man diese Aussage so hart missinterpretieren kann?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Bitte auf eine englisch gestellte Frage auch Englisch antworten (jeglichen Erklärtext in Englisch). Außerdem ist eine Rückfrage in einer Antwort schlecht aufgehoben, das ist nur in Kommentaren sinnvol (erfordert 50+ Rep). Bitte diese wertende rhetorische Frage entfernen (Edit-Button unter der Antwort.